# On $x^3+y^3+z^3 = 1$ and a Pell equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

Given,

$$(1-ac+bc)^3 + (a+c^2-ac^3)^3 + (ac^3-b-c^2)^3 = 1\tag{1}$$

where,

$$a,b,c,r = 12qrt,\;\;  3(q-r)(3q+r)t,\;\;  3s^2t^2,\;\; p-18qs^3t^3$$

then $(1)$ holds true if $p,q,s,t$ satisfies,

$$p^2-3(108s^6t^6-1)q^2=s\tag{2}$$

For $s=1$, this gives the Pell equation,

$$p^2-3(108t^6-1)q^2=1$$

which, starting with fundamental solution $p_1, q_1 = 216t^3-1,\; \pm12t^3$, gives an infinite family of *polynomial* parameterizations to $(1)$.

*Question: Other than square $s$ and $s=3$, is there any other integer $s$ such that $(2)$ has a non-trivial solution in the integers?*

Comment: try wolfram alpha

Comment: Please clarify your quantifiers.  For instance, do you want an $s$ so that, for every integer $t$, the equation (2) has an integer solution $(p,q)$?  As stated, your question just asks for an $s$ for which (2) has an integer solution $(p,q,t)$, and certainly there are many $s$'s with that property.

Comment: Not necessarily an $s$ such that for every integer $t$, that (2) has a solution. Just some appropriate constant integers $s,t$.  (Treated as a Pell-like equation, it is easily seen than an initial solution $p_1, q_1$ gives rise to an infinite other $p_i, q_i$.) Other than square $s$ and $s=3$, what other $s,t$ did you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are other integers $s$.  Just put $t=0$, so the equation becomes $p^2+3q^2=s$.  Then pick any integers $p$ and $q$, and most likely $p^2+3q^2$ won't be either a square or $3$.  For instance, if $p=2$ and $q=1$ then $s=7$.

If you require that $t$ be nonzero, then there are still solutions to (2) for other integers $s$ besides squares and $3$, for instance $s=12$ works with $t=1$, $q=2$, and $p=62208$.

Comment: I forgot to specify that $t\ne0$ as $a,b,c$ become zero as well. However, I noticed that as you pointed out, with $t=1$, then $s=12$ or in general, $s=3n^2$ works because of the identity, $(486n^7)^2-3(108(3n^2)^6-1)n^2=3n^2$.

Comment: Incidentally, in light of your identity, for $s=3n^2$ one can take $t$ to be any integer, since $(486n^7t^3)^2-3(108(3n^2t)^6-1)n^2 = 3n^2$.  Now it's reasonable to modify your question to ask whether there are any $s$ other than squares and $3n^2$ for which equation (2) has a solution $(p,q,t)$ with $t$ nonzero.